# Synapse Dedicated Pool vs Partitioned PARQUET

Tags: parquet, partitioning, azure-synapse

I'm not being able to get data from the partition columns using CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE.

On serverless I can use the "filepath()" function but I didn't find any equivalent on dedicated pools. Columns are NULL.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myTable
    (   col01   int
       ,col02   Date
       ,col03   varchar(8000)
       ,col04   int
       ,col05   float
       ,col06   float
       ,col07   bigint
       ,col08   datetime2
       ,col09   varchar(8000)
      )  
    WITH (
        LOCATION = '<<datalakepath>>/parquet_dir/',  
        DATA_SOURCE = SilverAzureDataLakeStore,  
        FILE_FORMAT = Parquet
    )
```

[image: Sample Result]

Source Path:
`A/B/TransactionsHistoryV1/LAST7Days/col01=5241/col02=2021-11-09/<<parquet_filename>>.snappy.parquet`

I also tried but with no success as well:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myTable
    (   col03   varchar(8000)
       ,col04   int
       ,col05   float
       ,col06   float
       ,col07   bigint
       ,col08   datetime2
       ,col09   varchar(8000)
       ,col01   int
       ,col02   Date
      )  
    WITH (
        LOCATION = '<<datalakepath>>/parquet_dir/*/*',  
        DATA_SOURCE = SilverAzureDataLakeStore,  
        FILE_FORMAT = Parquet
    )
```

Any Suggestions?

I also tried to use Delta, but looks like **Apache Delta still not supported on Dedicated Pools**.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, both the Spark pool and serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics support Delta Lake format. Serverless SQL pools do not support updating Delta Lake files. Only tables in Parquet format are shared from Spark pools to a serverless SQL pool.

> This is an excepted behaviour when using Delta Lake partitioned views.

**Note:** Unfortunately, it is not possible to use the filepath function with format=delta.

If you are creating the partitioned views on top of Delta Lake storage, you can specify just a root Delta Lake folder and don't need to explicitly expose the partitioning columns using the FILEPATH function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW YellowTaxiView
AS SELECT *
FROM  
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'yellow',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'DeltaLakeStorage',
        FORMAT='DELTA'
    ) nyc
```

> You can use the FILEPATH function with Partitioned views.

If you have a set of files that is partitioned in the hierarchical folder structure, you can describe the partition pattern using the wildcards in the file path. Use the FILEPATH function to expose parts of the folder path as partitioning columns.

```
CREATE VIEW TaxiView
AS SELECT *, nyc.filepath(1) AS [year], nyc.filepath(2) AS [month]
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'parquet/taxi/year=*/month=*/*.parquet',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'sqlondemanddemo',
        FORMAT='PARQUET'
    ) AS nyc
```

For more details, refer to [Create and use views using serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/create-use-views).

Comment: The question is about dedicated pool, not serverless.